postgres 14 - select * including a large json column returns slow
I have a table in an Aurora postgresql DB on AWS, that has a JSON column, which stores relatively large JSON data, and an index on ID column.
If I run a sql, that has a where condition on the ID column, it returns pretty fast, which is expected as its using the index scan.
But if run a "select *", the query took more than 10 secs to return more than 3000 rows.
Below is the explain plan details of the "select *",
Seq Scan on public.table as l (cost=0..121.57 rows=3357 width=146)
Timings: 0.668 ms

Node type   Count   Time spent  % of query
Seq Scan    1       0.668 ms    100%

Rows
Rows X  Actual  Plan
↓ 1.02  3397    3357

Relation name   Scan count  Total time      % of query
Node type       Count       Sum of times    % of relation
public.table    1           0.668 ms        100%
Seq Scan.       1           0.668 ms        100%

Note: same "select *" returns less than 500ms in VSCODE.
Just wondering why the "select *" runs such slow in pgadmin4? Thanks

Could you please share the results from explain (analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for your SQL statement? In plain text, not an image

I have added the explain plan details in text. Thanks.

0.668 milliseconds, that’s pretty fast. No idea why pgAdmin is so slow, try another tool like psql or anything else. Also check your network settings, the database connection.

500 milliseconds in your VSCode is imho already slow for a query that doesn’t take one millisecond

not sure if its because of the render of each json column in the result grid. If I do a select on all columns, without the JSON column, then its pretty fast. in pgadmin4, its down from 10 seconds to 168ms. in vscode, its down from 500 ms to 80ms.
